# Pagination information and Total Records

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

How to show pagination information and total records like "Showing 1 to 10 of 61 entries" ?

I am trying to show total records using length property of records data but it is not changing after filter and sort.

Answer (score 0):

Showing {{((+dt.first+1))}} to {{+dt.first+ +dt.rows}} of {{dt?.length}} entries